# Precompiled headers for large projects

Tags: c++, qt, precompiled-headers

```
SDK1 \
    LIB1 \
        ...
    LIB2 \
        ...
    ...
SDK2 \
    LIB1 \
        ...
    LIB2 \
        ...
    LIB3 \
        ...
...
APPS \
    UTIL1 \
        ...
    UTIL2 \
        ...
    ...
    APP1 \
        ...
    APP2 \
        ...
    ...
```

I've got a large qt-project with hundreds pro-files and structure like pictured upon. I want to add precompiled headers and i've got several questions.

1. How many headers should i create: one per every APP or one per every pro-file (include all UTIL and LIB directories) or one per every SDK and APPS folder?
2. Should i add my precomp.hpp at the start of every file that include some dependencies that mentioned in it? Asking because in examples on the github some peoples do it and some doesn't.
3. What should i do with usage intersections: imagine that APP1 is using APPS\UTIL1, APPS\UTIL3, SDK1\LIB1, SDK2\LIB1, SDK2\LIB2, and for example APP2 is only using APPS\UTIL1 and SDK1\LIB1 and i have different precompiled headers for APP1 and APP2. Does the compiler understand which one to use without my assistance? If i should include precomp.hpp to every file which i want to build faster should i add all precompiled headers that possibly can have effect on this specific file?

Answer (score 1):

So, after some experiments i would like to answer my own questions and give some advices:

1. On building, .pch-file realy should be created for every subproject with PRO-file to achieve maximum building acceleration, including all SDK-s, LIB-s, APP-s and UTIL-s, so you should specify your `precomp.hpp` in every pro-file. But you should remember, that if you are using single `precomp.hpp` for every subproject some of them may start to take more time for build instead of reducing it, because the includes list in `precomp.hpp` may be excess for this particular subproject and hence the whole time of building will increasing. Plus to it, every builded .pch-file is quite a big (in my project it has ~100Mb of size) so if you have some problem with free space on your build machine you should be careful.
2. `precomp.hpp` should be included at the top to all cpp-files which have dependencies, mentioned in this file. Also i recommend to put `precomp.hpp` to the place in project which could be easily accessed from every subproject where it is neccessary.
3. I see two ways of handling this problem: you may create several precomp.hpp-files and specify them exclusively for every pro-file you need to, or you can make single `precomp.hpp` with macroses inside and several complile definitions in pro/pri-files. Personaly i was using the second approach and i think it's more convenient and it's reducing the number of excess code in pro-files.